# Load html WITH static resources from Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to create a basic website on Node.js in order to learn.
I have an html with some css and js files for the site.
I want to serve this pages from Node.js, so I can make ajax calls to this later.

This is the code I have so far:

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

It loads the html correctly, but it does not find the resources css/js.

How should I implement a basic web server, where I can specify the page to return with the css/js resources I need?

Or maybe the question should be, is this the correct way to make the webpage using node?

Comment: check express-static module for serving static assests such as js css etc. also you will eventually want to use res.render instead of res.sendFile to be able to put some dynamic data into views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using express, so best way is to define your public folder where you are putting your `css` or `js` files to make it available as static resource -

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

```
public
 -css
  -style.css
 -js
  -script.js
```

then in your index.html file refer as -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

Comment: So, I added this line before the `app.get`. with the folder my resources are.
How should be the url to serve them now?

Comment: @Pablo yes add it before your routes

Comment: Yes, but how should now access that files?